Can't apply image to the ground in Babylonjs
I am adding ground here and wanted to add image which is in the same directory as this file. I can't add image to the ground, pls help
    createGround(scene: BABYLON.Scene, width: number, height: number): BABYLON.Mesh {
        const ground = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateGround("ground", { width, height }, scene);
        const groundMaterial = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("groundMaterial", scene);
        groundMaterial.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 1) // Green color
        groundMaterial.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("./background.png",
            scene, true, true, BABYLON.Texture.TRILINEAR_SAMPLINGMODE);
        (groundMaterial.diffuseTexture as any).uScale = 1; 

I tried adding absolute path but it also did not work.
